# Coda 2 "Source" options are disabled, can't add git info

Tags: git, versioning, coda

I'm trying to set up a new site in Coda 2.0.14 and whenever I get to the Source panel all of the options are disabled. Screenshot attached. I can't select or edit any of the fields. Any ideas? This seems to happen whenever I fill out the "Local Root..." field, but no matter what I enter as the root (new folder, old folder, different paths, etc.) this problem occurs.

I'm using OS X 10.9.4 and Git 2.0.1

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for and deleting any hidden .git folders which may be preventing Coda from showing the Source options screen.

The following command, when ran in Terminal, will show your hidden files in Finder.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

When finished, this command will hide files again.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```